# Pandas groupby-aggregation not working after shift() operation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregation, shift

I was analyzing a Kaggle project and found below inconsistency:

We have a sales data for store (1, 2, 3) and items (1, 2, 3, 4, 5). The original author, wanted to calculate sum and mean for every combination of the store, item and period (month/year). and since s/he thought we should have visibility of only previous months when predicting the sales for current month, s/he decided to shift the sales vectors by 1. But this causes the issue that last month's Sales for store 1 product 1 becomes part of store 1 product 2.

```
data.groupby(["store", "item", "period"]).sales.agg(["sum", "mean"]).shift(1)
```

My initial thought was to maybe move shift operation after grouping but before aggregation.

```
data.groupby(["store", "item", "period"]).sales.shift(1).agg(["sum", "mean"])
```

Looking at outputs from the second line of code is very surprising for me. seems like aggregation didnt respect groupby indexation after shift was executed.

Screenshot showing code and output:
[image]

Has anybody experienced anything similar? is shifting really removes indexation from groupby operation?

*EDIT:*

adding the link to Original kaggle workbook:
https://www.kaggle.com/ekrembayar/store-item-demand-forecasting-with-lgbm

Comment: Do you mind posting the code or sharing the link to the notebook?

Comment: The result of `groupby agg` is (typically) a DataFrame so using `shift` after `groupby agg` is `DataFrame.shift` not `Groupby.shift` (which is why the whole frame is shifted not just within groups). The same is true the other way `Groupby.shift` followed by `DataFrame.agg` you end up with the sum and mean for the entire dataframe. You'll need to use multiple groupbys to perform both operations in group.

Comment: @Luke added the link, thanks!

Comment: @HenryEcker your explanation is spot on! maybe one more think you can help, you know, shift works perfectly well on rolling() function, so if you shift the group and do rolling afterwards, you are not overlapping the groups defined in the group by; so dataframe.shift object still reserves groupby index information?

df.groupby(["store", "item"]).sales.shift(1).rolling(i).mean().values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using 2 `groupby()` successively, as follows:

```
(data.groupby(["store", "item", "period"]).sales.shift(1)
     .groupby([df["store"], df["item"], df["period"]]).agg(["sum", "mean"])
)
```

This way, we don't need to change the original values of `sales` and yet we can get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
data['sales'] = data.groupby(["store", "item", "period"]).sales.transform('shift')
print(data.groupby(["store", "item", "period"]).sales.agg(["sum", "mean"]))
```